# How to create a "fake filesystem" that forwards system calls to my program?

Tags: linux, filesystems, driver

I would like to write a tool that can be used to mount archives such as tar, tgz, zip, 7z, etc. to some directory for as long as it's running, such that I can then open it with whatever file manager I want.

To do this, I would somehow need to make a fake filesystem that forwards system calls such as opening and reading files to my program. How would I did this? Would I have to make my own filesystem driver, or does a library for this already exist?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse) is what you're looking for, in principle. One implementation of the archive-mounting you're looking for is/was `archive mount`, but I am unsure how well it is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general. I will assume you want to write your program using Python because it is what I would do.

Chosen the language, now we need to look for examples of somebody doing something similar. Github would do the trick:

- To mount wikipedia: [wikifs](https://github.com/trewtzu/wikiFS/blob/master/wikifs.py)
- To mount Google Music: [GmusicFS](https://github.com/EnigmaCurry/GMusicFS)

N.B. Wikifs is least than experimental, but the script is short and servers perfectly as example.

For **python** the most popular library is **fuse-python**.

Happy hacking

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a FUSE filesystem. It is explained in this article and there is an example in python: https://thepythoncorner.com/dev/writing-a-fuse-filesystem-in-python/

No need to call this "fake filesystem", because for linux everything can be a file, so you write just a "filesystem".